# Show that any set of vectors containing a linearly dependent subset is again linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that any set of vectors containing a linearly dependent subset is again linearly
dependent.

I think you're supposed to show this by contradiction, but not sure how.

I tried:

Let V be a linearly independent set of vectors {$v_1,...v_n$} such that $a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$=0 and $a_1=...=a_n=0$. Then, V is a subset of {$v_1,...,v_{n+1}$} and $a_1v_1+...+a_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$ where $a_1=...=a_{n+1}=0$. Therefore, the set {$v_1,...,v_{n+1}$} is again linearly independent.

Comment: If the coefficients are all zero, you will get zero regardless of whether or not your set is independent.  Hence the calculation given does not make any useful progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\{x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$ is dependent.  Then there are coefficients $a_1,\ldots, a_m$, not all zero, such that $$a_1x_1+\cdots+a_mx_m=0$$
Now, let $n\ge m$, and consider the set $\{x_1,\ldots, x_m,x_{m+1},\ldots, x_n\}$.  Now, take $b_1=a_1, b_2=a_2,\ldots, b_m=a_m$, and $b_{m+1}=b_{m+2}=\cdots=b_n=0$. Since the $a_i$'s were not all zero, the $b_i$'s are not all zero either. We have $$b_1x_1+\cdots+b_nx_n=a_1x_1+\cdots a_mx_m=0$$
Hence $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is dependent as well.

Comment: Which is to say, "Prove the contrapositive"

Comment: I proved the statement given in the title, directly, using the definition of a set of vectors being dependent.

Comment: @pjs36: As far as I can see, this is a direct proof.

Comment: Yep, I completely misread everything - wow!